# Are there non-floating underwater neck straps for underwater digital cameras?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-straps, underwater

About 6 years ago I bought the Canon AKT-DC1 kit for my Canon D10.  The underwater straps were fantastic.  It had shoulder and neck straps that allowed you to swim rigorously with the camera in a way that wrist straps don't allow you to do without banging the camera around.

I've ordered the Olympus TG-3 since my Canon D10 is getting a bit old and I'm not sure how much longer the seals will last.  But I can't find a neck strap for the TG-3.  Are there not any good generic neck straps for underwater cameras?  I'm an avid snorkeler so floating straps aren't interesting to me since I tend to dive quite a bit for good photos.

[image: Canon AKT-DC1 neck strap]

Comment: I've googled the AKT-DC1 kit and am still not clear what I'm looking at. Perhaps more info about what made those straps good would help someone make a recommendation. At the very least, it'd clue me in about what makes them good!

Comment: I realize most cameras do not have the snap & lock feature.  However I think this image might clear it up for you.  http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/ciu/3c/cb/7807810ae7a092724cac1210.L.jpg

Comment: This sounds like something I would make myself using bungee cord and perhaps bolt-snaps. That way I could make it the way I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the snap and lock feature, [which you note most cameras do not have](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/52034/are-there-non-floating-underwater-neck-straps-for-underwater-digital-cameras#comment89380_52034), there does appears to be nothing particularly special about the Canon AKT-DC1 neck strap. Especially if you want it to *not* float, straps made of any material should do.

As [@Mikkel notes](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/52034/are-there-non-floating-underwater-neck-straps-for-underwater-digital-cameras#comment92218_52034), you can "make" your own with bungee cord and bolt-snaps. Bungee cords come in various lengths with different types of hooks and buckles attached. Other options include neoprene, nylon webbing, and quick-release buckles.